# Embedded Kafka for testing without spring

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, apache-kafka, integration-testing

Is there any framework/tool which can provide Embedded Kafka instance (Kafka Brokers) without any dependency of spring in Java/Scala?

Can someone please provide a working example of it?

Comment: Maybe TestContainers can assist you? https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/kafka/

Comment: Depending on how you consume/produce Kafka messages, would be easier and more stable to mock

Comment: Those people who closed the question, please review your judgment skill. Although this question is sort of seeking library, it is also asking for working example and people want this. That is why it is upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.

Check out the samples on Confluent examples repo, they use embedded instances of Kafka, ZooKeeper, and Confluent Schema Registry (an example: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/65f770c75988afc33d3813a1aa4f9f7818fe81d8/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WikipediaFeedAvroExampleTest.java#L51)

[TestContainers](https://testcontainers.org/modules/kafka) might be another alternative.

[Citrus](https://citrusframework.org/samples/kafka/) has also support for that.

If you are using Scala, check out the [Embedded Kafka library](https://github.com/embeddedkafka/embedded-kafka)

Comment: As far as I can tell, Citrus reuses spring-kafka-test, which the OP stated they didn't want. The Confluent code isn't a good example because it's not a scalable solution since you're pulling source code around - https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/tree/65f770c75988afc33d3813a1aa4f9f7818fe81d8/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/kafka